# How to remote connect MySQL on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Raspberry Pi with IP = 192.168.137.165 and my Windows laptop has IP = 192.168.137.1. I write C# code to connect MySQL from my laptop.

I also have changed file my.cnf  on ras PI as follows:

```
   #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
   bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

And on MySQL, configure to allow access from any IP address:

```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON luan_van.* TO 'root_b'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
   flush privileges;
```

Here my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace bp_3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string constring = "Server=192.168.137.165;Database=luan_van;Port=3306;User ID=root_b;     Password=root";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlDataAdapter myData = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            myData.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from tt_nhanvien;", conDataBase);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myData);
            conDataBase.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connect");
            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And it error "Can't get hostname for your address"

What wrong with it, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Useful information: Instead of hardcoding the connection string, you can use the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class to generate it for you. Set the properties accordingly and be sure to always get a valid connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your conf file

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

That should cure the issue

Comment: Yes, its success. Thank you very much